# How to create new operator by using existing operator with current motion?

Tags: vimscript, cursor-motions, operator

```
function! OperatorFunc(type, ...)

  " how to call another operator with current motion?

  " do other stuff

endfunction
```

Is it possible to get motion text?  such as get `iw` from `yiw`

Answer (score 1):

Visually select motion text, execute existing operator:

```
function! OperatorFunc(type, ...)

  " change op to desired operator
  call ExecuteOperator(a:type, a:0 > 0, 'op')

  " do other stuff

endfunction

function! ExecuteOperator(type, visual, operator)
  if a:visual
    exe 'norm gv'.a:operator
  els
    exe printf('`[%s`]%s', a:type ==# 'line' ? 'V' : 'v', a:operator)
  endif
endfunction
```